# Convert Excel Table to HTML keeping the format (borders, background colours) using Python

Tags: python, html, excel

I'm trying to convert an Excel table to HTML using Python. But I want to keep the original formatting of the table. For example, I have 3 lines with the colour grey and in bold and every cell value is centered. The table also has borders.

I was able to convert to HTML using pandas, however it only keeps the borders, the other formatting characteristics are gone.

Can someone help me please?
I've already check this post ([Python - Excel to HTML (keeping format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68273994/python-excel-to-html-keeping-format)), but did not understand how it works :(

Thanks!!

Comment: `pandas` was creating for calculations and it doesn't care for formatting. You have to use modules created specially for `Excel` - like `xlwings`, etc. [Python Resources for working with Excel - Working with Excel Files in Python](https://www.python-excel.org/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.